# RFC822 Timezone Parsing in Java

Tags: java, date, iso8601, rfc822, rfc3339

I have a JS date that is being converted by Dojo into RFC822 format.  The function call -
dojo.date.toRfc3339(jsDate), generates the following date - 2007-02-26T20:15:00+02:00.

I have an application that uses a Java date SimpleDateFormat to parse in the dates generated above.  I am having problems parsing this date format due to the timezone.  I have attempted to use

yyyy-mm-DD'T'hh:mm:ssZ

This fails as the 'Z' for timezone doesn't expect a ':' character.  Does anyone know how I would specify a pattern to handle a RFC822 date with the ':'?

revision:

Thanks for correctly interpreting what I am trying to do :) I was meant to say the date is generating in RFC3339 and I needed RFC822. Looks like I will have to override the JavaScript. I was hoping that I wouldn't have to do that and could specify a date format pattern without having to modify any Java Code as the date format is simply injected into a Spring bean of an application.

Just for completeness, is there a way to specify in a date format expression to ignore characters in the sequence (without doing String manipulation/replacement)? In this case I'd be saying ignore any ':' or just ignore the timezone all together?

Answer (score 4):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateUtil {

    public static Date ParseRFC3339DateFormat(String p_date)
    {
        try{
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
            String dts = p_date.replaceAll("([\\+\\-]\\d\\d):(\\d\\d)","$1$2");
            return formatter.parse(dts);
        }catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This works

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-DD'T'hh:mm:ssZ");
format.parse("2007-02-26T20:15:00+02:00".replaceAll("([\\+\\-]\\d\\d):(\\d\\d)","$1$2"));
```

(Note I've taking the final colon out of the format after the 'Z' format specifier.)

Answer (score 2):

RFC822 does not allow a colon to be in the time zone portion of date. It expects just the 4 digits. The name of that Dojo method indicates that it is using RFC3339. It seems that is practically the same format as [ISO8601](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522251/whats-the-difference-between-iso-8601-and-rfc-3339-date-formats). It just so happens that [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net) has [`ISODateTimeFormat`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html) which is ISO8601 compatible if you are able to use that library. The method [`dateTimeNoMillis()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTimeNoMillis%28%29) looks like a match with the Dojo format. It really is nicer than the standard Java date and time API. Otherwise highlycaffeinated's suggestion would be the way to go.

**Updated in response to Jamen's update**

Isn't there a way to have Dojo use a format that doesn't include the timezone? Then you can adjust the format on the Java side to match. I don't know much about Dojo and I haven't been able to find any documentation on the toRfc3339 function it provides.

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8 you can use:

```
Instant.from(DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME.parse( rfc822Time ) );
```

FYI: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME

Answer (score 1):

I'd strip the ':' out of the timezone and use the format you have above.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using dojo.date.toRfc3339(jsDate) you could create your own function with a custom format string.

Something like the following would remove the colon and should be parsable by your java format.

```
function toRfc3339String(jsDate){
    return dojo.date.locale.format(jsDate,{selector: 'date', datePattern:'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ssZ'});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this generically without Java 7. I have asked 2 questions in `StackOverflow` on this, within 2012, so **there is a solution that does not need any third party libraries**.

Just check the implementation presented in the description of my [latest question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040143/generic-support-for-iso-8601-format-in-java-6), which also points to the earlier one that discusses exactly this issue.