# Compare News Feed Item Dates with different formats in Android

Tags: android, date, android-calendar

I want to sort an array of rss feed news items by date/time with latest coming on top. i am getting news from a number of sources, can anyone tell how can i compare these 3 date/times.

Thu, 25 May 2017 06:35:38 GMT

Wed, 24 May 2017 17:54:02 +0500

Thu, 25 May 2017 07:27:17 +0000

Comment: Create an enum of DateFormater and check against the incoming dates

Comment: this worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43782928/1171434