# Converting time-stamp to milliseconds in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-api, timestamp, rfc3339

I have a date which is of format `20170622T164322Z`. How to convert it into milliseconds(epoch time) in javascript. I am new to javascript, kindly help

Comment: You do notice that this timestamp has no milliseconds in it, don't you? 2017/06/22 at 16:43:22 + timezone. No milliseconds.

Comment: I framed the question in a wrong way. Please refer the edit

Comment: Do you mean extract or convert? You do use both verbs in your question though they are no synonyms.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318634/how-to-convert-date-in-rfc-3339-to-the-javascript-date-objectmilliseconds-since

Comment: @yuriy636 I did refer it, but my format is different from, what they have used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) in your project, you can do this:

```
moment("20170622T164322Z").unix()
```

Example running on the console of the browser:

```
moment("20170622T164322Z").unix()
1498149802
```

Btw, moment.js is just great when dealing with date time.

Comment: I just did. I think it wasn't well worded before, that's why people give -1

Comment: Also, if my answer does address your question, please consider accept it as a correct answer. Thanks!