# How to return the current timestamp with Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I am trying to understand the MomentJS API. What is the appropriate way to get the current time on the machine?

```
var CurrentDate = moment();
```

vs

```
var CurrentDate = moment().format();
```

I'm trying to understand their docs, and it's not apparent what to use.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-a-moment/

Comment: The current time as what? unix timestamp?

Comment: I would imagine the RFC3339 or whatever the internet standard id for returning back to clients, etc

Comment: Returning back to the client... hummm... I guess that you are getting it in nodejs and sending it to the browser wanting to convert it again to a momentjs instance?

Comment: Sorry, have you found my answer helpful?

Comment: absolutely, i think :)  asked a quick question regarding `var now = new Date().getTime();
       userObject.registered = moment(now).toDate();`

Answer (score 381, accepted):

Here you are assigning an instance of momentjs to CurrentDate:

```
var CurrentDate = moment();
```

Here just a string, the result from default formatting of a momentjs instance:

```
var CurrentDate = moment().format();
```

And here the number of seconds since january of... well, unix timestamp:

```
var CurrentDate = moment().unix();
```

And here another string as ISO 8601 ([What's the difference between ISO 8601 and RFC 3339 Date Formats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522251/whats-the-difference-between-iso-8601-and-rfc-3339-date-formats)):

```
var CurrentDate = moment().toISOString();
```

And this can be done too:

```
var a = moment();
var b = moment(a.toISOString());

console.log(a.isSame(b)); // true
```

Comment: would this be acceptable? `var now = new Date().getTime();
       userObject.registered = moment(now).toDate();`

Comment: @Cmag, I don't understand the question, but just take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/coma/bLe31qq0/ , as you can see there, even after a second the moment instance keeps the same time since it's frozen, is the same behaviour as new Date().

Comment: so its the same behavior?

Comment: @Cmag, Yes, it is, think of momentjs as a Date object on steroids and use the toDate method only when you are working with third party libs needing a raw Date object. With momentjs, complex time calculations are more than easy, are pleasant. I crafted a datepicker with it: https://github.com/coma/MomentPicker/blob/master/src/MomentPicker.js

Comment: Also the `.format('x')` option will generate a timestamp string.

Comment: Answered the first question AND the follow-up question I had when faced with a deprecation warning. Brilliant, thanks!

Answer (score 143):

`moment().unix()` you will get a unix timestamp (in seconds)

`moment().valueOf()` you will get a full timestamp (in milliseconds)

Comment: To format
`
var CurrentDateUnixTimestamp = moment().unix();
  moment.unix(CurrentDateUnixTimestamp).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");`

Comment: What's difference between `unix` timestamp and `full` timestamp? I suppose the `full` timestamp is what indicates the ~time flow~ in milliseconds since 1970 Jan 1 but I can't figure out the other one.

Comment: `.unix()` gives you the Unix timestamp in seconds, `.valueOf()` gives you the Unix timestamp in milliseconds (AKA what I've always thought of as a Unix timestamp).

Comment: @AndrewKoster I would point out that the UNIX timestamp (POSIX) is actually defined as the number of UTC *seconds* elapsed since 1/1/1970 00:00:00 ignoring leap seconds. So it's actually redundant to say "unix timestamp in seconds" and the recent obsession with using milliseconds causes me no end of frustration. One should only use milliseconds when it is necessary to the application. Most applications do not need this granularity and I was disappointed when I found out that moment js `valueOf` uses millis because it is reinforcing a bad pattern imo.

Comment: i.e what you always thought of as UNIX timestamp is actually incorrect. You have them backwards. There is a reason why moment js calls the function `unix`...

Comment: Yeah, Moment is right to call the seconds one `unix`, I'm the one who has it backwards in my head. If anything, they should rename `valueOf` to something involving milliseconds (i.e. `unixMilliseconds`).

Answer (score 44):

Try to use it this way:

```
let current_time = moment().format("HH:mm")
```

Comment: Craft4 is correct, please refer to: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/ for how to use `Format`, but not sure the answer is exactly aligned with the question.

Comment: simple and beautiful

Answer (score 42):

Still, no answer.
Moment.js - Can do anything but such a simple task.

I'm using this:

```
moment().toDate().getTime()
```

Answer (score 18):

If you just want the milliseconds since 01-JAN-1970, then you can use

```
var theMoment = moment(); // or whatever your moment instance is
var millis;

millis = +theMoment; // a short but not very readable form
// or
millis = theMoment.valueOf();
// or (almost sure not as efficient as above)
millis = theMoment.toDate().getTime();
```

Answer (score 13):

Try this

```
console.log(moment().format("MM ddd, YYYY HH:mm:ss a"));
```

```js
console.log(moment().format("MM ddd, YYYY hh:mm:ss a"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Get by Location:

```
moment.locale('pt-br')
return moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss')
```

Comment: What does .locale() do ?

Comment: Hi @Charith_32, basecally this translate your defined format. EX; .format('LLL')

Answer (score 5):

Try this way:

```
console.log(moment().format('L'));
moment().format('L');    // 05/25/2018
moment().format('l');    // 5/25/2018
```

Format Dates:

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // May 25th 2018, 2:02:13 pm
moment().format('dddd');                    // Friday
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // May 25th 18
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');     // 2018 escaped 2018
moment().format();                          // 2018-05-25T14:02:13-05:00
```

Visit: https://momentjs.com/ for more info.

Answer (score 4):

Current date using momment.js in DD-MM-YYYY format

```
const currentdate=moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY"); 
console.log(currentdate)
```

Answer (score 3):

to anyone who's using `react-moment`:

```
import Moment from 'react-moment'
```

inside render (use `format` prop to your needed format):

```
const now = new Date()
<Moment format="MM/DD/YYYY">{now}</Moment>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that you can have the whole data information in an object with:

```
const today = moment().toObject();
```

You should obtain an object with this properties:

```
today: {
    date: 15,
    hours: 1,
    milliseconds: 927,
    minutes: 59,
    months: 4,
    seconds: 43,
    years: 2019
    }
```

It is very useful when you have to calculate dates.

Answer (score 1):

To use am / pm with moment, here is a snippet from a react component

```
import Moment from 'moment';

const time = Moment().format("hh:mm a")
```

For reference please remember [Moment.js is considered a legacy project](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) that can carry performance overhead
[image]