# How to convert ISO 8601 time in golang?

Tags: go

What is the equivalent code in golang for the following shell command ?
`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T%z`

Answer (score 265, accepted):

If you're looking for a simple, but not perfect solution consider using `time.RFC3339` constant.  But also know that there are differences between ISO8601 which are too complex for this answer.

See https://ijmacd.github.io/rfc3339-iso8601/ for differences and also has a handy test file generator to show differences. There is also a good discussion on SO here [What's the difference between ISO 8601 and RFC 3339 Date Formats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522251/whats-the-difference-between-iso-8601-and-rfc-3339-date-formats)

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "fmt"
)

func main(){
    fmt.Println(time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339))
}
```

[golang Time.Format](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The others may work, but they would certainly confuse someone who was unfamiliar with the code.

Comment: ISO 8601 and RFC3339 are not technically the same thing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522251/whats-the-difference-between-iso-8601-and-rfc-3339-date-formats

Comment: From what I could tell, RFC3339 is a stricter version of ISO 8601. So it is probably safe to use the RFC format if a system expects the ISO.

Comment: Note: It appears that converting to UTC first is not necessary:
https://play.golang.org/p/UDrkigOfgIc

Comment: @lukeic that's because golang playground is working in UTC timezone. Try to run on your local machine.

Comment: this answer worked for me: 
`time.Now().UTC().Add(time.Hour * 24).Format(time.RFC3339)`

Answer (score 55):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(time.Now().UTC().Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05-0700"))
}
```

Comment: Note that if you include `UTC()`, the formatted string will always  UTC offset +0000. To preserve the local time offset, omit `UTC()`.

Answer (score 12):

I had the following spec:

```
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ
```

with the final `Z` being explicitly present in the examples.

Here's how I dealt with it:

- first I found the `time.RFCxxx` that was the closest to my target
- I copied its value
- I fiddled with it until I found the expected result

which is

```
2006-01-02T15:04:05.999Z
```

Comment: What is the RFC value to get this result?

Comment: "I fiddled with it" -- why we can't have nice date things.

Comment: This doesn't explain a thing. Show the code.

Comment: The documentation for the time.Layout constants explains the format specifiers: https://pkg.go.dev/time#pkg-constants

Answer (score 7):

Replacing the sign in the format with a Z triggers the ISO 8601 behavior. Which is exactly time.RFC3339. If you are wanting the string output to end in 'Z' what you need to do is convert to the UTC zone.

```
package main    
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(time.Now().UTC().Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"))
}
// this is the same format used by RFC3339. just a note on why.
```

Comment: This does not seem to return correct timezone value followed by Z

Comment: I'm sure that it does print the correct time stamp. This is the same format used in time.Time. See https://golang.org/src/time/format.go?s=15423:15465#L78

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I could format to ISO8601 basic (no colons) : `fmt.Println(time.Now().UTC().Format("20060102T150405Z"))` in fact it works the other directions as well: `tm, err := time.Parse("20060102T150405Z", "20220201T204925Z")`

Answer (score 7):

ISO8601 allows for variable levels of granularity.  You can have just a year, year+month, year+month+day, add a time portion, and optionally have a timezone portion.  Go's built-in time parsing, however, requires you to know ahead-of-time which parts will be included.

The github.com/btubbs/datetime library provides a more flexible parser that can handle all the commonly used ISO8601 formats.  See https://github.com/btubbs/datetime

Disclosure: I wrote that library.

Comment: "UnmarshalJSON methods support easy parsing of ISO 8601 timestamps from external systems"

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works as advertised, parses "20220201T204925Z"  which is super useful when you cant have colon in the format. I wish there was a datetime.Format(...) function as well.