# How do I parse an ISO 8601 Timestamp in Go?

Tags: go, time, timestamp

I know I need to use a time layout in Go (as shown here https://golang.org/src/time/format.go) but I can't find the layout for an ISO 8601 timestamp.

If it helps, I get the timestamp from the Facebook API. Here is an example timestamp: `2016-07-25T02:22:33+0000`

Comment: see https://pkg.go.dev/time#pkg-constants

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I found this layout to work: `"2006-01-02T15:04:05-0700"`

Comment: I don't know why this answer got downed vote. `time.RFC3339` doesn't work but this layout work.

Comment: `time.RFC3339` does not work for ISO 8601. Example: https://play.golang.org/p/gIi7D5KuWa

Comment: This is not correct; it's the RFC 3339 subset of ISO 8601. Notably, it fails to parse 20060102T150405Z.

Answer (score 13):

The problem here is that [RFC3339 requires](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6) the zone offset to be given as "+00:00" (or "Z" in case of UTC) while ISO8601 allows it to be "+0000".

From [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6):

> ```
> [...]
>
> time-numoffset  = ("+" / "-") time-hour ":" time-minute
> time-offset     = "Z" / time-numoffset
>
> [...]
>
> full-time       = partial-time time-offset
> date-time       = full-date "T" full-time
> ```

So instead of the `time.RFC3339` layout

```
"2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"
```

you have to use:

```
"2006-01-02T15:04:05Z0700"
```

Comment: There is a problem with your examples. From your quote of the RFC, it's either "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z" or "2006-01-02T15:04:05+07:00". You can't have both "Z" and a timezone offset.

Comment: @thibpat In a timestamp you can't, but in a *layout string* you can. The "Z" in that case [means](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants) that a "Z" should be printed **instead** of an offset when the time zone is UTC.

Comment: Thanks for the precision, that makes a lot more sense, sorry for not catching it right away.

Answer (score 1):

RFC3339 is equivalent to ISO 8601.  Specifically, it has identical format, RFC3339 just has stricter requirements (example, it requires a complete date representation with 4-digit year).

[What's the difference between ISO 8601 and RFC 3339 Date Formats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522251/whats-the-difference-between-iso-8601-and-rfc-3339-date-formats)

So you can use the constant `time.RFC3339` as your layout.

Comment: @TravisSmith Take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9346)

Comment: That issue is about not understanding what "Z07:00" means in the layout, but here the problem is about the colon.

Comment: RFC 3339 is NOT equivalent to ISO 8601; it is a subset of the allowed formats of ISO 8601. Notably, using time.RFC3339 fails to parse 20060102T150405Z correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You have that to use the some layout of your date.

```
 data   := "2022-01-24T00:00:00.000-03:00"
 layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000-03:00"

 dataTime, err :=  time.Parse(layout, data)
```